# Do Mana Beans profit from fortune enchantment?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

Do i get more mana beans with Fortune enchanted axes / TC hatchets with lapis?

Comment: How many Mana Beans do you get without the Fortune Axe, and how many do you get with it?

Answer (score 1):

No, fortune does not effect Mana Beans.

Comment: Could you please put down a source? While this information may be completely viable, we have know way of knowing.

Comment: Simple, I asked Azanor in IRC, my logs have been long expunged since then

Comment: Thats not really enough to convince me, sorry

Comment: It's also been mentioned in videos I believe of Forgecraft playthrough. But the easiest way to prove it, make a bean farm, say about 100. When they are full grown, harvest without fortune and count them. Repeat this say about 5 times to be certain. Then repeat 5 more times with fortune. This question is really pointless, it's like asking what color my shirt is....all I have to do is look.

Comment: [This](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Enchanting#Enchantments) has all the information you need on enchantments. It has no information of "Fortune" affecting mana beans. As far as this source goes, it only affects certain blocks. (The answer is correct, by the way, even without a 100% fool-proof source)